# ArrayList<Integer[]> not working in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to make an `arraylist` with `int[]` as objects

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> b= new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    Integer[] a= new Integer[2];
    for(Integer i=0;i<20;i++){
        a[0]=i;
        a[1]=i;
        b.add(a);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        System.out.println("line"+i+"= "+b.get(i)[0]+" "+b.get(i)[1]);
    }
```

and the result I get is this

[image]

instead of the values( 0 0 1 1 etc), is seems that has saved only the last.
I have also tried with type int instead of Integer but the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider initializing `a` within the loop as otherwise you are just writing over the same array the whole time.
Instead of

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> b= new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    Integer[] a= new Integer[2];
    for(Integer i=0;i<20;i++){
        a[0]=i;
        a[1]=i;
        b.add(a);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        System.out.println("line"+i+"= "+b.get(i)[0]+" "+b.get(i)[1]);
    }
```

consider this:

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> b= new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<20;i++){
        Integer[] a= new Integer[2];
        a[0]=i;
        a[1]=i;
        b.add(a);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        System.out.println("line"+i+"= "+b.get(i)[0]+" "+b.get(i)[1]);
    }
```

As the point is for each loop iteration to make a new array and store new values rather than overwrite the existing ones as if you step through your code you may notice you how don't ever allocate a new array within the loop.

Comment: thank you a lot it worked! I thought you simply add the inside of this object

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare a new array for each element you're going to add. Otherwise they all reference the same memory. Declare the array inside the for loop instead of before the loop.